# Grails pass arguments to module using resources plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, plugins, grails, resources, arguments

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and I want to use both resources plugin as well as jquery ui, the problem comes when I want to switch to a different jquery ui theme. I cannot give the theme argument.

I use this tag:

```
<r:use module="jquery" />
<r:use module="jquery-ui" theme="smoothness" />
```

but doesn't work, also tried with themeCSS attribute and no effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default jquery-theme resource in your own local resources definition (like /conf/AppResources.groovy). To do that add overrides section like:

```
modules = {
...
    overrides {
        // this overrides the default ui-lightness theme from jquery-ui plugin
        'jquery-theme' {
            resource id:'theme', url:'/css/themes/my-theme/jquery-ui.custom.css', attrs: [media: 'screen, projection']
        }
    }
...
}
```

Adjust the url accordingly to point to your theme css downloaded from a ThemeRoller. Then simply use

```
<r:require module="jquery-ui" />
```

jquery-ui module depends on jquery-theme and will pull it according to your overridden definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this plugin makes it so hard but anyway, if you want to change the theme you need to specify (inside of head tag):

```
<jqui:resources themeCss="${g.resource(dir:'/css/jquery-ui/theme/smoothness', file:'jquery-ui-1.4.4.custom.css')}" />
```

Than you need to place your template files (css file and also images folder) into your application css folder (web-app/css). This should work